# SDN4 - cannot orderBy object from repository

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

After update to Spring Data Neo4j 4.1.3 RELEASE, I cannot use OrderBy. For example I call findByIdOrderByNoAsc(String id)

I need to use workaround and create a Collection.sort method just for this purpose. In Spring Data Neo4j 3 still work fine, but after update, I just realize that my List of object, is not ordered Ascending or Descending.

This is my Repository :

```
package com.sample.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

import com.sample.model.Item;

public interface ItemRepository extends GraphRepository<Item> {

    Item findByIdOrderByNoAsc(String id);

}
```

Is SDN4 already not support this kind of function? How can I sort my Object from Repository without using Pageable?

Answer (score 1):

SDN 4 does not yet support the static *orderBy for derived finders, but you could use the `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` till this is supported

e.g.

`List<Cinema> findByLocation(String city, Sort sort);`

Comment: So I just add Sort parameter in my method? like this : Item findByIdOrderByNoAsc(String id, Sort sort);
And input new Sort(Direction.ASC) or new Sort(Direction.DESC) ?

Comment: Yes to the parameter, but don't put the OrderByNoAsc in your method name. It should be findById(String id, Sort sort)